# Customize input array and get them in output

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want get (handling) values input and checkboxes as following example, without change in name element in checkboxes, I tried as following but this don't work:

**DEMO**: http://codepad.viper-7.com/4ldRKV

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    //foreach ($_POST['cDA'] as $idx => $value) {
        foreach ($_POST as $idx => $value) {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($_POST);
        }
    //}
}
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="cDI[]" value="F1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDA[0][]" value="11" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDA[0][]" value="11" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDC[1][]" value="22" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDC[1][]" value="22" checked>
    </br>
    <input type="text" name="cDI[]" value="F2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDA[0][]" value="33" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDA[0][]" value="33" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDC[][]" value="44" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDC[][]" value="44" checked>
    </br>
    <input type="text" name="cDI[]" value="F3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDA[0][]" value="55" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDA[0][]" value="55" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDC[][]" value="66" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cDC[][]" value="66" checked>
    </br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want in output as: ( how should change html and php to getting following result? )

```
Array
(
    [cDI] => Array
        (
            [0] => F1
            [1] => F2
            [2] => F3
        )
    [cDA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                    [1] => 11                    
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 33
                    [1] => 33                    
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 55
                    [1] => 55                    
                )

        )
    [cDC] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 22
                    [1] => 22                    
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 44
                    [1] => 44                    
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 66
                    [1] => 66                    
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `cDA[0][]` as the name of a collection of input boxes, it will turn `$_POST['cDA']` into this:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 11,
        1 => 11,
        2 => 33,
        3 => 33,
        4 => 55,
        5 => 55,
    ),
);
```

Using `cDC[][]` as the names of your input boxes, you will end up with this array in `$_POST['cDC']`:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 11,
    ),
    0 => array(
        0 => 11,
    ),
    0 => array(
        0 => 33,
    ),
    0 => array(
        0 => 33,
    ),
    0 => array(
        0 => 55,
    ),
    0 => array(
        0 => 55,
    ),
);
```

To make them group properly you have to set the value between the first square brackets explicitly:

```
cDA[0][]
cDA[0][]
cDC[0][]
cDC[0][]

cDA[1][]
cDA[1][]
cDC[1][]
cDC[1][]

cDA[2][]
cDA[2][]
cDC[2][]
cDC[2][]
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hopROf)